# Trying to add a library to a make file

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Hi this is my make file (I have very little make file experience sorry)

```
PROJECT_ROOT = $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

OBJS = Angle.o \
       AppControlTimer.o \
       CableAngle.o \
       CFunctionObject.o \
       SonarDGCUArrayData.o \
       SonarDGCUCommsTCP.o \
       SonarDGCUEthernetClient.o \
       SonarDGCUFinsPacket.o \
       SonarDGCUMotorMemoryArea.o \
       SonarDGCUSensorsData.o \
       SonarDGCUSensorsMemoryArea.o \
       SonarDGCUThread.o
       
LIB = libFins.a
INCPATH = ../../
INSTALL_DIR = /opt/s2193/lib64

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),debug)
    CFLAGS += -g
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),run)
    CFLAGS += -O2
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),linuxtools)
    CFLAGS += -g -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
    LDFLAGS += -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
else
    $(error Build mode $(BUILD_MODE) not supported by this Makefile)
endif
CFLAGS += -MMD -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-vla  
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJECT_ROOT)../target/nar/log4cxx-0.11.0.TUS1-noarch/include/ -c -Wall
CFLAGS += -I${INCPATH}include -DLINUX

LDFLAGS += -L$(PROJECT_ROOT)../target/libs/ -llog4cxx

CXXFLAGS += -DBUILD_WITHOUT_HAL -DDBG_LVL=7

CXX += -std=c++11
CC += -std=c11

.PHONY: all clean install

all:    $(LIB)
    
$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)src/%.cpp
    @echo ".cpp.o!! "$<
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    
%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)src/%.c
    @echo ".c.o!! $<"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    
clean:
    rm -fr $(LIB) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)


install: $(LIB)
    install -m 755 -d $(INSTALL_DIR)
    install -m 644 $(LIB) $(INSTALL_DIR)

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

when I use the file I get undefined reflectances I'm trying to use the library
LDFLAGS += -L$(PROJECT_ROOT)../target/libs/ -llog4cxx
but I'm not sure how to add it to the file for reference when building libfins.a

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! You should add the command an output to the question.

Comment: the make file is called from a jenkins build job the error I get is 
/data/jenkins/data/workspace/S2193_DG_Adapter/DGCUAdapterApp/../libFins//libFins.a(SonarDGCUCommsTCP.o): In function `CSonarDGCUCommsTCP::CSonarDGCUCommsTCP(CSonarDGCUEthernetClient*, char const*, int)':
SonarDGCUCommsTCP.cpp:(.text+0x2f0e): undefined reference to `CArrayTrainer::pLogger'
SonarDGCUCommsTCP.cpp:(.text+0x3492): undefined reference to `CArrayTrainer::pLogger'

and I think its because I have not told it were to find the liblog4xcc.so which I'm trying to do with the LDFLAGS. I know it needs to be added.

Comment: First you should check the LDFLAGS indeed appear in the command that generates the error. If so, then double-check the library is indeed at the location pointer to by the `-L`-flag.

Comment: the lib is were it should be and is pointed to I think I need to add LDFLAGS to the commands in the make file but I'm not sure were, as I said my make file knolage is very limited

Comment: You still haven't shown us the command line generating the error. Should be a line linking the executable.

Comment: I'm assuming its one of the lines in the makefile but my make knowledge is limited and hence the question.

Comment: There's no explicit rule for linking executables in the presented makefile, suggesting you get the implicit rule. Should work as it uses the LDFLAGS variable.

Comment: Make will print each recipe which should then end up in the output just before the error.

Answer (score 0):

`liblog4cxx` supports `pkg-config` like any other sanely packaged library.

#### **Stop writing flags by hand for libraries that you haven't made.**

```
CXXFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags liblog4cxx)
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs liblog4cxx)
```

If you are really curious about flags your library needs, go ahead and run these two commands in your terminal, then leave it at that. Flags needed on your system are not necessarily flags needed on mine, that's why `pkg-config` exists, and people who made the library know better than you what it needs or does not need.

At the same time, `pkg-config` allows to expect a specific version of a library and all dependencies of your dependency are resolved transparently, without you having to do anything about it, and in fact you cannot do anything about it, because you don't know when or how the library or any of its dependencies will change, this becomes even more insane to manage yourself if you're linking statically. When using `pkg-config`, you just tack on `--static` and it gives you all the extra necessary flags.

Comment: I don't think this will work in this case as I have a bespoke run time environment based on redhat thus we import the lib into the build area and link to them, so the above two lines in a command window says the package was not found

Comment: @AlanJ Import from where? Even if you compile locally, the package is usually autogenerated by a build system, then it's as easy as `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<library install path>/lib/pkgconfig`. The package in question is simply a plaintext file that provides necessary information, and you can find it easily via `find "<library install path>" -type f -name '*.pc'` If it's not there, you really should talk to your team about getting shit together, because [apache did all the work for you](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4cxx/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L116-L118).

Comment: the system is stand alone so all the libs we use are down loaded from a repository at the version required to match the run time system and built in a jenkins job so this is why we end up wittering flags by hand, this is not really my area and I'm working with what I am supplied.

Comment: @AlanJ well, I told you how to do it properly. If you have some insanely stupid requirements that really prevent you from doing this, then install `liblog4cxx` properly, matching the version you're provided, run these commands manually and copy the flags into makefile and it should work for most cases, until it will not. I still don't understand which part of your setup prevents the build system from outputting one ***very important*** plaintext file that makes everything more robust and simpler. This is on the level of stupidity matching writing your own header files for the dependency.